# Best way to Track User Interaction on Site (Google Analytics)?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I trying to figure out if there is already an existing 3rd party app that can solve my problem before I would have to roll out my own.

Basically when a user comes to my site, I want to track what they are doing. Say they search something I want to log that they did a search.

I know Google Analytics can through custom events log that a user did a search, but I want it not only for everyone who did the search but per individual user.

For example

User 1 comes to my site and does 3 searches
User 2 comes to my site and does 10 searches
User 3 comes to my site and does 1 search

With GA, I could setup a Custom event on that search and it will record that 14 searches was done, what is great, but I also would like to be able to drill down from those 14 search and find that User 2 did 10 searches, User 1 did 3 seaches and etc.

Comment: Have you looked at the User Explorer reports? That should give you what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

User ID level references have to be custom built. These are different from anonymous client ids on GA, and they have a tonne of limitations- PII must be excluded. It comes with a different view. In non user ID enabled views, unique user id metrics are calculated using client ids. Cross device reports will have a 90 day time before they expire. All this aside, User id info can not be queried as a dimension in reports in web/APIs, but accessible via the core reporting API. Good luck!